# Selenium- WebButton need to be clicked only once in a loop

Tags: eclipse

I am writing a selenium script in eclipse for adding user to an application by fetching the user values from the excel sheet.

In this scenarion a button "Add" will be exist at the first user addition, once its clicked a textbox "Add_Name" will appear where  name need to be added. In loop for the second user addition selenium will look for the "Add" webelement, but it does'nt exists so its throwing error.

I have used the below code for the elements existance even then i'm getting the below error. Please help me in this.

Code Used : //Click on the "Add New Button"

```
            if(browser.findElements(By.id("ext-gen72")).size()!=0){
                browser.findElement(By.id("ext-gen72")).click();
            }
```

else{
Continue rest of the steps....
}

error:Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917132/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible

Comment: Please Check the HTML code snippet of Both button 'Add' and 'Add_name'.  Also when you say after clicking it changes from Add to Add-name , Check  the locater which you are using to locate the add Web-element.