# ElementNotVisibleException while trying to find a text cum dropdown menu in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have to click a text cum drop down box and select a particular value from the dropdown.

Here is the HTML code snippet for the input box is:

```
<div class="ui-multiselect-selected-container">
    <div class="ui-multiselect-dropdown-arrow"></div>
    <span class="ui-multiselect-selectbox-container ui-sortable">
        <div class="ui-multiselect-selectedbox" id="multiSelect-631489830" data-value="BMW 2015 National Video YouTube" title="BMW 2015 National Video YouTube" style="display: none;">
          <div class="ui-multiselect-selectedbox-close"></div>BMW 2015 National Video Y...</div>
    </span>
    <div class="ui-multiselect-prompt" title="" style="max-width: 265px;">BMW 2015 National Video YouTube </div>
    <input type="text" class="ui-multiselect-autocompletebox nosubmit" placeholder="Add Filter" data-minwidth="52" style="width: 52px;">
</div>
```

I am trying to use the following xpath expression:

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-multiselect-selected-container']//input[@class='ui-multiselect-autocompletebox nosubmit']")).click();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have one of those two problems:

1. May be this code snippet is generated on runtime and you are trying to select them while they are not visible. if this the case so please find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917132/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible).
2. May be your web driver does not support the client side java script or partially support like 'HTMLUnit', so select the suitable driver.

I hope this could help.

Comment: I am using Chrome Driver.